# Is there a difference between a button being deactived and disabled?

Tags: javascript, java, mobile

I am writing requirements and in order to prevent any conceptual confusions I want to make sure, the term I use is aligned with technical perspective. Is there a difference between a button being deactive and disabled technically?

Comment: I believe that, technically, the correct expression is `disabled`. You can either disable/enable a component or hide/show it. For instance, on [jQuery's  FAQ](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/), it's mentioned `disabled`and `enabled`.

Comment: In my opinion, business requirements should be written independently of the technical approach used to implement them. With that said, I think that "deactive" and "disabled" mean the same, it means the button is not usable at a certain moment, although "disabled" is more oftenly used.

Comment: Could you please give an example of what you mean using the case above as the starting point?

Comment: @Baderous, but since both terms are related, and the OP mentions the word `technically`, one could take into account the one that's technically more familiar to a large set o people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In technical perspective there isn't anything called button being deactive, we can only enable/disable or show/hide a button. To prevent any confusion during design and implementation, you should use Enable/Disable for a button.

Answer (score 3):

Activate/Deactivate is mostly used for an Account/Feature not for the button, Buttons can be enabled/disabled for activating or deactivating a feature or an account.

Comment: interesting point, but I dont quite get what are you trying to say by buttons can be enabled for activating a feauture or vice-versa. Are you trying to say something like "by enabling a start button I can activate the make a payment feature." ?

Comment: I feel enable/disable is a subset of Activate/Deactivate, I have an active account in stackoverflow but most of the features are enabled based on our privileges....and the buttons are liked with a feature, so they should be mostly enabled/disabled... My apology for the confusion....

Answer (score 2):

Technically it should be disable as usually you disable a button  not deactivate it.

Deactivate may also mean that you are destroying the button while disable means that you are just not enabling the normal functioning of the button.